# Wordpress return JSON and resolve "plugin spaceholder"

Tags: json, ajax, wordpress, lazy-loading

I' building a wordpress theme which should be able to lazy load specific pages etc. Therefore my idea was to have something like this:

**/pages/contact** => displays the page

**/pages/contact?json** => returns json

All in wall this is working good, but i have a problem when i use a ninja form for example. The content of the page will have something like this: [ninja_form id=1] - when i now lazy load the page, this snippet is not resolved. Is there a function to resolve it?

Code example

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $data = array(
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'content' => get_the_content(),
        'image' => wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) )
    );

endwhile;

// return json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

wp_send_json($data);
//echo json_encode($data);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to call this with my content string:

```
$data = array(
  'title' => get_the_title(),
  'content' => apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content()),
  'image' => wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) )
);
```

calling apply_filters was the solution